# Datasource configuration in java

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, datasource, jboss5.x

I have one query regarding datasource configuration.

I had configured one data source in server. Where my JNDI name is "MyDS".

To acquire the data-source in JBoss environment i had used like `"java:/MyDS"` in persistence, spring even in Birt reports.

But when i am running same thing in Tomcat environment, then it is showing error that unable to get the data-source.
I had googled about tomcat datasource communication, where i had seen like `"jdbc/MyDS"`

So, my query is what is the difference between above two types of configurations? (`java:/MyDS` and `jdbc/MyDS`) and how can i use the common configuration for both the servers (tomcat6 and jboss 5.1.0.GA).

Please help me.

Comment: Somewhere in your Tomcat installation (e.g. in META-INF\context.xml) you should find a definition of a resource: e.g. <Resource name="jdbc/MyDS..." .../>

Comment: @Darius X, actually i had configured my tomcat datasource ins CATLINA_HOME/conf/context.xml. I did not find any definition there. Please heip me